# weblogic.wsee.ws.init.WsDeploymentException: The WebLogic Server 9.x-style policy is not supported in JAX-WS

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, weblogic-10.x, wsse

I have developed a webservice and deploy on weblogic 10.3 now i want to implement webservice security in that so that client provide username password token in header to access my webservice.

I create file weblogic-webservices-policy.xml with policy entries

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
 <webservice-policy-ref xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <port-policy>
   <port-name>AudioCall</port-name>
   <ws-policy>
    <uri>policy:Auth.xml</uri>
    <direction>inbound</direction>
   </ws-policy>
 </port-policy>
 </webservice-policy-ref>
```

but i am getting following error

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: weblogic.wsee.ws.init.WsDeploymentException: The WebLogic Server 9.x-style policy is not supported in JAX-WS
 web services.
        at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.framework.jaxrpc.TubelineDeploymentListener.createServer(TubelineDeploymentListener.java:85)
        at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSTubelineAssemblerFactory$TubelineAssemblerImpl.createServer(WLSTubelineAssemblerFactory.java:204)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl.<init>(WSEndpointImpl.java:201)
        at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSContainer$WLSEndpointFactory$WLSEndpointImpl.<init>(WLSContainer.java:577)
        at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSContainer$WLSEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(WLSContainer.java:530)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

Caused By: weblogic.wsee.ws.init.WsDeploymentException: The WebLogic Server 9.x-style policy is not supported in JAX-WS web services.
        at weblogic.wsee.security.wssp.deploy.WssDeploymentListener.process(WssDeploymentListener.java:55)
        at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.framework.jaxrpc.TubelineDeploymentListener.createServer(TubelineDeploymentListener.java:82)
        at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSTubelineAssemblerFactory$TubelineAssemblerImpl.createServer(WLSTubelineAssemblerFactory.java:204)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl.<init>(WSEndpointImpl.java:201)
        at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSContainer$WLSEndpointFactory$WLSEndpointImpl.<init>(WLSContainer.java:577)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Mar 5, 2012 3:38:40 PM UZT> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID '1330943919750'
for task '0'. Error is: 'weblogic.application.ModuleException: [HTTP:101216]Servlet: "org.csapi.wsdl.parlayx.account_management.v3_1.service.A
ccountManagementService_AccountManagementImpl" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "ParlayXAccountManagement.war".
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: weblogic.wsee.ws.init.WsDeploymentException: The WebLogic Server 9.x-style policy is not supported in JAX-WS
 web services.
        at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.framework.jaxrpc.TubelineDeploymentListener.createServer(TubelineDeploymentListener.java:85)
        at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSTubelineAssemblerFactory$TubelineAssemblerImpl.createServer(WLSTubelineAssemblerFactory.java:204)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl.<init>(WSEndpointImpl.java:201)
        at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSContainer$WLSEndpointFactory$WLSEndpointImpl.<init>(WLSContainer.java:577)
        at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSContainer$WLSEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(WLSContainer.java:530)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createEndpoint(EndpointFactory.java:231)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:514)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:557)
        at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSDeployedServlet.getEndpoint(JAXWSDeployedServlet.java:183)
        at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSServlet.registerEndpoint(JAXWSServlet.java:96)
        at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSServlet.init(JAXWSServlet.java:61)
        at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSDeployedServlet.init(JAXWSDeployedServlet.java:54)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:241)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:283)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:64)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:58)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:48)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:539)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:1976)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup(WebAppServletContext.java:1950)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1869)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3126)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1512)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:486)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:41)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:200)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:247)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:41)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:27)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:1267)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:41)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:409)
        at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:43)
        at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:569)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:323)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDelive
```

Regards,
imran

Answer (score 3):

The error was because WebLogic Server 9.x-style policy is not supported in JAX-WS webservices. for detail check following link

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/webserv_sec/message.html#wp210122

Please look at following blog if its required to support old policy in JAX-WS

http://kingsfleet.blogspot.com/2008/12/simple-custom-policy-example-using-jax.html

Regards,
imran

Comment: Second link is very helpful. I really like one of commenters approach (Micheal) who said that it's better for portability that you leave policy file in web-app/WEB-INF/policies directory, but doesn't use @Policy annotation. Rather specify policy file after deployment using admin console.

What would be the best is to specify policy file in some weblogic-specific xml deployment descriptor so one doesn't have to do it manually after deployment.