# weblogic 10.3.6 issue

Tags: weblogic-10.x

I have upgraded the WebLogic server from 10.3.5 to 10.3.6 for my application and upgraded the jars to the latest which are available with WebLogic 10.3.6.

I have created `wlfullclient.jar` and and the deployment was going fine.

When I try running the test cases for my application they were failing with the following error:

```
com.sun.xml.ws.util.ServiceConfigurationError:
weblogic.wsee.jaxws.tubeline.TubelineDeploymentListener:

Provider:`weblogic.wsee.wstx.wsat.tube.WSATTubelineDeploymentListener` is specified in jar:

> file:/root/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/wseeclient.jar!/META-INF/services/weblogic.wsee.jaxws.tubeline.TubelineDeploymentListener

but not found at
- com.sun.xml.ws.util.ServiceFinder.fail(ServiceFinder.java:241)
- com.sun.xml.ws.util.ServiceFinder.access$100(ServiceFinder.java:141)
- com.sun.xml.ws.util.ServiceFinder$LazyIterator.next(ServiceFinder.java:376)
    weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.WLSServiceDelegate$WLSTubelineDeploymentListenerRepository.<init>(WLSServiceDelegate.java:355)
- weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.WLSServiceDelegate.<init>(WLSServiceDelegate.java:89)
- weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.WLSProvider$ServiceDelegate.<init>(WLSProvider.java:632)
- weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.WLSProvider.createServiceDelegate(WLSProvider.java:143)
- weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.WLSProvider.createServiceDelegate(WLSProvider.java:117)
- weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.WLSProvider.createServiceDelegate(WLSProvider.java:88)
- javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:56)
```

While using WebLogic 10.3.5 the testcases were passing without issue.
I finally found that there is no folder named `wsee` in the new `wlfullclient` which was created for the new release (WebLogic 10.3.6).

Please help me how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be problem with the webservices.

This discussion might help [wsse JAXWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9565299/weblogic-wsee-ws-init-wsdeploymentexception-the-weblogic-server-9-x-style-polic)